# How to get the output to be printed in the right form to the file?

Tags: python

I have a list of documents. Like this:

```
['nn', 'known', "tsutsumi's", 'father', 'yasujiro', 'sowed', 'seeds', "family's", 'dominion']
['un', 'secretary', 'general', 'kofi', 'annan', 'appointed', 'special', 'representative', 'iraq', 'help', 'improve', 'communication', 'iraqi', 'leaders']
['confidence', 'debate', 'repeatedly', 'chided', 'opposition', 'speakers', 'joining', 'groups', 'bitter', 'critics', 'nationalists', 'past']
```

Each document is a list of strings.

I am conducting some pre-processing on these documents wherein I am removing suffixes that differentiate these words.

Here is my code:

```
    results=[]

    with open('/Users/mtr/Documents/Stemtry.txt') as filer:
        for line in filer:
           results.append(line.strip().split())

    result=[]
    final=[]
    temp=[]

    def stemm(n):
        for suffix in ['ing', 'ly', 'ed', 'ious', 'ies', 'ive', 'es', "'s", 'ment', "s", "'ve", "'t", "'"]:
            if n.endswith(suffix):
                return n[:-len(suffix)]
        return n

   for eachitem in results[:10]:
       for n in eachitem:
           r=stemm(n)
           final.append(r)
   print(final)
   result.append(final)

   datafile=open("Stemmingg.txt", "w")
   for each in result:
       for every in each:
           datafile.write(each+' ')
       datafile.write("\n")
   print(datafile)
   datafile.close()
```

My issue is that after removing the suffixes, the program is putting all the words of all the documents into one big list. However, I want them to be returned in the original form(i.e list of documents as earlier) after pre-processing. How should I modify the code?

Comment: I cant understand  difference between `final` and `result` in your code

Comment: Are the original words both single and double quoted? Why do you not give a delimiter for split in line 5?

Comment: @Arman final is just a list of the words. I was trying to use results to append the words into separate documents but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final keeps accumulating. re-define it in the outer loop:

```
for eachitem in results[:10]:
    final = []
    for n in eachitem:
        r=stemm(n)
        final.append(r)
   result.append(final)
```

or even better, use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
for eachitem in results[:10]:
    final = [stemm(n) for n in eachitem]
    result.append(final)
```

Comment: Oh yes, it worked. The final was getting overloaded.! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to run stemm() on each word of each line of a document?

Here is the code:

```
final = [[stemm(x) for x in line] for line in result]
```